# 2-input CMOS NOR gate circuit operation

Tags: logic-gates, cmos

Someone please explain to me how the circuit below operates as NOR gate. I have created a truth table next the diagram based on my understanding of basic MOSFET switching. For the output to be equal to Vdd, transistors Q1 and Q2 should be conducting while Q3 and Q4 must be non-conducting. It appears to me that the output can never be HIGH.

[image]

IN A | IN B | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | OUT

---0-----0----ON--ON--OFF--ON-----0

---0-----1----ON--OFF-OFF--OFF----0 (floating?)

---1-----0----OFF-ON--ON---ON-----0

---1-----1----OFF-OFF-ON---OFF----0

Comment: In your first line of the truth table why would Q3 and Q4 be in different states with the same inputs?

Comment: Q3 (N-channel) connected to LOW A must be non-conducting. Q4 (P-channel) connected to LOW B must be conducting, if I'm not terribly mistaken.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the arrow direction. Where did you get the diagram? Link?

Comment: It's from a paid review platform. I think they got it somewhere else tho because I checked with google and confirmed it's indeed a NOR gate

Comment: Just noticed the arrow directions. It's a mistake in the diagram; Q4 should be an N-channel MOS.

Comment: Plus the substrate of Q2 must be tied to Vdd; not to Output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the transistor polarities, and draw them correctly.  It looks like Q1 and Q2 should be P channel, and Q3 and Q4 N channel.  You've got them drawn every which way, and even inconsistent with themselves.

Details matter in engineering.  Once you correctly show the transistor polarities, the operation of the circuit should become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 and Q2 are P-channel mosfets - they conduct when their inputs go *LOW*, while the N-channel mosfets - Q3 and Q4 conduct when their inputs are tied *HIGH*.

So When INA is LOW: Q1 is ON and Q3 is off

When INB is low: Q2 is ON and Q4 is off

When both are tied low, it leaves us with both Q1 and Q2 creating a path from Output to VDD while Q3 and Q4 floating which completely disconnects Output from Ground. In other words, Output is HIGH when INA == INB == LOW.